# I want to stop a countdown on inactive tab also do a task after countdown ends

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website. Where people have to watch banner ads. The problem is with countdown. I want a countdown timer but thing is i want it to be pause when the browser tab is inactive. And also it will run reward script when the timer ends and redirect me to homepage.

Thanks

I am expecting a Countdown timer, A pause script and reward script.

Comment: This website is not for requesting code.

Comment: Please I want it. I will not do this again

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how much [effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) is expected.

Comment: Ok just tell me is will the setInterval CountDown stops on inactive tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the tab is no longer the active tab, it automatically throttles (slows down) any javascript running on the page. For example, a loop that runs several times per second might now run once per minute.

However, that is not what you want - you want the code (a) to detect when the page is no longer the active tab, and (b) to stop/restart the timer the moment the tab gets/loses the focus.

> To answer your specific comment-question: The `setInterval CountDown` will not STOP on an inactive tab, but the loop will slow down dramatically

There are two things you need to implement:

a) Service Worker - service workers are not throttled when a tab loses the focus. So you can create a service work whose only job is to loop every second and monitor whether the tab has the focus. (*Every time the service worker sends a message back to the main page, the page wakes up in order to process that request - basically, service workers can be used to stop the tab from being "put to sleep".*)

https://medium.com/@adithyaviswam/overcoming-browser-throttling-of-setinterval-executions-45387853a826#root

b) Visibility API - this api will tell you if the tab's state - does it have the focus or not?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/#state-passive

There are lots of demos on YouTube re how to implement each of these. [Here is one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJRu3pmmN-4&list=PLyuRouwmQCjl4iJgjH3i61tkqauM-NTGj) re creating/implementing a service worker.

This is the knowledge you need to solve your problem - it is now up to you to actually code the solution.